# Double Dashes in next.js variable does not work

Tags: next.js

Having a double dash (--) in a variable in next.js throws an error.
JSX expressions must have one parent element.

The variable name is 'constitution__subtitle--bar'.

{`${styles.constitution__subtitle} ${styles.constitution__subtitle--bar}`}

Why does next.js not allow double dashes (--) in a variable?

Answer (score 0):

Dashes in variable names in js are not allowed.

Try to use `${styles["constitution__subtitle--bar"]}`